# Wobble in rear hub

Tags: hub, wobble

I have a 97' cannonade f1000 that has had disc brakes installed. The rear hub developed a wobble after only 200 miles. I took it back to the shop that built and installed my set up. I thought they fixed it but after only 50 miles the rear hub showed signs of beginning to wobble again. Was it a bad build or did Shimano provide my local shop with defective hub?

Comment: A wobble could be many different things: the hub bearings are bad, the wheel wasn't built right, the spokes are losing tension, you put a ding in the rim, etc. etc.  Unless you can give more details (photos are useful), I don't think we can answer your question.

Comment: So you have a 19 year old bike?  Why only 200 miles till the wobble developed?  If its a used bike then could be many things.  Did the shop fit a new hub to the wheel (hundreds) or did they simply reset the bearings (cheaper) ?

Answer (score 2):

As commented, there are a multitude of reasons this could be happening.  However, they all boil down to roughly two categories, a defective hub, which should be a warranty issue for the manufacturer, or improper setup/adjustment from the shop (and subsequent possible damage) which should be the shop's issue.  From your stand point of just having bought a new wheelset (I am assuming the wheelset is new with the brakes) you should treat both the same way, take it back to the shop you purchased it from.